# how to optimize my Genetic Algorithm results

Tags: java, optimization, genetic-algorithm, crossover

I've already programmed Genetic Algorithm for the Multi-depot Vehicle Routing Problem with time window problem and it works perfectly but the results are not good enough. I am comparing my results with Solomon bench Marks and all his instances the results are less than mine.

I used the Best Cost Route Crossover BCRC method for the crossover
and my chromosome is a vector a all customers.

could you please suggest to any techniques or methods I should do to optimize my GA results.

Thank you
best regards.